# Why are some words combined into a single word while others stay as two words?

Tags: compounds

Examples:

- Anyone
- Anything
- Anytime
- Anywhere
- Everyone
- Everything
- **Every time**
- Everywhere
- **No one**
- Nothing
- **No time**
- Nowhere
- Someone
- Something
- Sometime
- Somewhere

Why is there a discrepancy? Is there any rule for determining when to use a single word vs. two words?

Comment: Well, "no one" probably remains two words to avoid a potentially-confusing spelling. Dunno about the rest, or a general rule, though.

Comment: I would have said "anytime" and "sometime" were controversial, also.  "My sometime drinking buddy" means my former drinking buddy, but events in the past happened "some time ago".  Similarly, I see "any time" a lot more frequently than "anytime", I think.

Comment: Agree. Re  **anytime/any time*: When do you want to go?" "Any time is fine with me." "But anytime I go anywhere, my annoying little sister wants to tag along!"  (**Anytime** is an adverb, akin yo _whenever_. **Any time** is a NP and can act as a subject))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Language is always changing, and most often in the direction of simplification. You can even see the evolution happening before your own eyes. ["All ready" became "already"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/already); "all right" is in the process, through usage and repetition, of becoming "alright" (if not in fact "a'ight"). It is [already accepted](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/alright) as an informal alternative to "all right" and I predict that it will supplant the two-word version altogether (!) except in the most formal writing (e.g., academic papers) within the lifetimes of many of us.

Comment: "Already", even as used by you, means "now and since a time prior to this". "All Ready" has never meant this.

Comment: @mickeyf: According to Dictionary.com, it has. Please visit the link I put on that sentence.

Comment: It's funny; I was unaware that "alright" had not already done this. Perhaps I mostly see it used in very informal contexts?

Comment: "A lot" is next

Answer (score 2):

Pure convention. Unfortunately, there isn't a logical reason why some of those are written as a single word, and some aren't. It's essentially a matter of tradition. Consider especially the case of "no one", which is very clearly a single phonological word with a single word stress, but which has never been accepted as a compound.

Comment: Like I said above, I think "no one" remains two words because it's not supposed to be pronounced /new-nee/. But come to think of it, I have seen it spelled "no-one", primarily in Victorian novels.