# Which words may start with "al-"?

Tags: etymology

Is there a rule which determines whether it allowable for a word to be "merged" with "**all**" to make a new word starting "**al-**"

e.g.

> 1)All together -> Altogether
>
> 2)All right -> Alright

The first is generally accepted. Whereas I believe the second is technically not (certainly my English teacher used to condemn it).

Comment: Related: [Is it “alright” or “allright”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12996/is-it-alright-or-allright)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll quote what my NOAD says:

> **USAGE** - The merging of *all* and *right* to form the one-word spelling **alright** is first recorded toward the end of the `19th century` (*unlike other similar merged spellings such as altogether and already, which date from much earlier*). There is no logical reason for insisting that all right be two words when other single-word forms such as altogether have long been accepted. Nevertheless, although found widely, ***alright*** remains nonstandard.

So, although alright is "older", altogether is considered to be standard.

Plus, as the [OALD](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/altogether) states, **altogether** and **all together** are not synonyms:

> Altogether and all together do not mean the same thing.
>
> - **Altogether** means ‘in total’ or (in British English) ‘completely’: *We have invited fifty people altogether. ◇ I am not altogether convinced by this* argument.
> - **All together** means ‘all in one place’ or ‘all at once’: *Can you put your books all together in this box? ◇ Let’s sing ‘Happy Birthday’. All together now!*

And, as @Matt Ellen reminded me (us), not even **all right** and **alright** are synonyms, see his comment.

Other terms are **already**, as mentioned above, and about the `al-` prefix, the Oxford English Dictionary, says:

> obs. form of all, retained in comp. in *albeit, almighty, almost, alone, already, although, always.*

Comment: also *all right* and *alright* are not synonyms. *All right* indicates a set of things are correct, or right (as in: "these turns are all right, it'll take us in a circle."). *Alright* is a synonym for OK as in "Are you alright?"

Comment: @Matt Ellen: yeah you're right, I'll add a reference to your comment.

Comment: @Matt Ellen: *alright* is an [alternative spelling](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/alright) of *all right*, only used in the *OK* sense.

Comment: @psmears: Well I'll be. I don't think I've used the uncontracted version before. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it's just a convenience, like words with the prefix **in-** followed by a p. Since n and p are hard to pronounce in a row, the n is replaced by an m, and all of a sudden we have a new prefix **im-**.

Comment: The prefix there is _im-_ not "imp-".

Comment: Yes, I know. That just seemed more convenient than "Words with the prefix **im-** followed by a **p**". Hm. That sounds good, actually. *Editing my post*

Comment: Eheheh yeah, plus it might get confusing to those who don't know which is the real prefix.