# Where did the second `L` in alright go?

Tags: etymology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which words may start with “al-”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23936/which-words-may-start-with-al)

The word *alright* comes from *"all right"*. Where did the second *l* go?

Similarly: *altogether* from *"all together"*.

Comment: related: [Which words may start with "al-"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23936/which-words-may-start-with-al)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link below gives the history of this spelling:

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alright

As to why this change is taking place, it isn't easy to give an answer. Perhaps its followers have decided that it should imitate the word *"fulfil",* where the double consonants were done away with when the two words **full** and **fill** were united.

Comment: I've never seen *fulfil*, only ***fulfill***.  Do you actually see fulfil in the wild?

Comment: @Brendon: In British English, yes, I see only "fulfil". I believe "fulfill" is the American spelling.

Comment: The existence of the two forms performs a useful function. There is a difference between 'Your answers to the exam questions were all right' and 'Your answers to the exam questions were alright'.

Comment: @BarrieEngland: Is there a difference in meaning? I see only a difference in spelling.

Comment: @Irene: (1) every answer was correct. (2) the answers were O.K. I think you would hear the difference if it was spoken.

Comment: In discussing the spelling, you have not set out the difference between the word *alright* and the phrase *all right*, leading to great confusion. In the example, it not always *fulfil* - even Word flags this spelling.

Comment: From your own reference, '*the first two years of medical school were alright* — Gertrude Stein' does not mean each of the years was OK, only that the period was generally OK.

Comment: @PeterShor: Thank you, too. I did see the difference when I heard myself speak both sentences.

Comment: This is strictly about writing, then? No one need resort to mention of spoken language.

Comment: @Kris: Word flags spelling which is not American. If you switch to UK English, things change. As for the difference in meaning, 1)I don't think OP asked for that 2)I wasn't aware of a difference in meaning until it was pointed out to me in a comment above. I thought that "alright" was a non-standard (and not accepted by many) variation of "all right".

Comment: @Kris: (continue) I believed (I still do actually, but since the language changes, I have to adjust) that both meanings explained by Peter Shor could be expressed by "all right". Apparently, I was wrong.

Comment: @Irene: I think this is one of those cases where American *spelling* (notwithstanding significant advances back in Webster's day) tends to be more conservative than British. Even for UK usage, NGram suggests the more recent *alright* is 5-6 times less common than *all right* - but it's maybe **20 times** less common in the US. We both seem to make the same *okay/all correct* distinction in speech though, so I really do think this is just a matter of how it's written down.