# All Right vs Alright when starting to speak

Tags: word-usage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it "alright" or "allright"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12996/is-it-alright-or-allright)

When giving a speech or presentation it's common to hear the speaker (including myself when I present) start out by saying "All right". "All right, let's get started.".

My questions are

- In this scenario, which is correct, "All right" or "Alright"? I suppose when listening to a speaker you wouldn't notice the difference.
- Follow up: Do they have different meanings based on context or is Alright a conjunction?
- Why do we use this phrase to actually get started? Is it to break the silence or is it a nice way to get the attention of the audience?
- Is it appropriate to use when writing? This would be more in the context of blogs, educational articles, tutorials, etc.

Comment: As to speech, they are identical.