# "All right" vs. "alright"

Tags: grammar, differences

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it “alright” or “allright”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12996/is-it-alright-or-allright)

Which is correct in English, "all right" or "alright"?

These expressions don't cause any problem in verbal communication but I confuse them while writing. To be frank, I sometimes use "all right" and sometimes "alright" without actually knowing which one is correct. If both of them are correct, how should I know which one to use in a particular case?

Comment: "Alright" is sub-standard usage.

Comment: @htoip: not so.

Answer (score 6):

Many people will insist on *all right*, but I have never used anything other than *alright*. There are precedents in *already* and *almost*. *Alright* has the advantage of allowing us to distinguish between *The answers were all right*, meaning they were all correct, and *The answers were alright*, meaning they were OK, but nothing special.

Comment: Of course, there are the Young Republicans... in which case, the kids are all Right.

Comment: @MT_Head: Alright.

Comment: Indeed, being "alright" has little to do with "all right". A guy who is alright could be wrong about a lot of things, or he could not be feeling all right today. "alright" is as unrelated to "all right", as "all ready" is to "already".

Comment: What about this example? I asked all the kids in my class a question. They all answered it correctly. They were all right. In this case alright is not right.

Comment: @Brad: Exactly.

Answer (score 0):

The meanings are very different.

**Alright** means okay; acceptable. **All right** means entirely, completely or totally right. And in this instance right could mean correct, or the opposite of left.