# Sugarcane or Sugar cane?

Tags: hyphenation, colloquialisms, compounds, word-formation, open-vs-closed-vs-hyphenated

Is there a difference between "sugar cane" and sugarcane? Is sugarcane wrong? What is the gramatical rule for joining two names like that?

I have found 13.500 entries on google for sugarcane, but 16.000 for sugar cane.

Is that a matter of style or grammar? What do you guys think?

Comment: have you looked at the pages with hits for each, to see if they're used differently?

Comment: the OED sites *sugar cane*. Webster's 9th New Collegiate sites *sugarcane* with the same definition. It seems there is favor on both forms.

Comment: That's exactly what I think: both versions are correct. There seems to be no standard even in news websites...

Comment: Scans are going to be hard to interpret, since, eg, one might talk of a "sugar cane crop" but of "sugarcane syrup".

Comment: Answered in general terms at [What's the most preferred spelling of auto fill, auto-fill, and autofill?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/146660/whats-the-most-preferred-spelling-of-auto-fill-auto-fill-and-autofill) [Jon Hanna's answer]; specific example general reference.

Comment: @HotLicks But one can just as easily speak of "[sugar cane syrup](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1389172301801109)" as "[sugarcane syrup](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1877705812012799)." The forms don't seem to be used in meaningfully different ways. Sometimes you will [find both together](http://www.southernmatters.com/sugarcane/bulletins/Pope/cane_syrup.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

Both forms are widely used, though the closed form has been more popular recently, more so in American English:

[image: Google NGram showing relative popularity of "sugarcane" and "sugar cane"]

The phenomenon of open compounds becoming closed has been covered in several previous questions, starting with [Why are some words combined into a single word while others stay as two words?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5419/)

Comment: That's a really neat chart.

Answer (score 0):

There is no grammatical difference -- it has nothing to do with grammar.  It's simply an arbitrary spelling convention.  Sugarcane is a compound noun, and these are spelled with a space dividing the parts, or a hyphen, or no character at all.  Sometimes one variant becomes more commonly used, but who cares?